# "bad" language in questions

Tags: discussion

I've come across a post edit and I wasn't sure what to do with it.

OP used the term `Googling my ass of` which was removed in an edit by another user. For me this kind of language is no issue but I guess some people might find it offending.

Is it ok to always approve these kinds of edits or do we draw a line at cursing and stuff like that?

Or, optionally, am I just overthinking it way to much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't find it offensive... But, for some reason, with other men it's all fine, if a girl reads that, I would have some objections.

I had the opportunity to work in teams with very smart programmers. In that environment there was a lot of swearing. After spending 1 day in that team you could swear for 30 minutes without repeating yourself.
Some code comments would involve swearing.

Now, the difference is that this is a public space. It's like an open space... You don't swear and use bad language when a customer is visiting your company.

And then is the debate, can `Googling my ass of` be considered bad language. From my point of view `ass` doesn't qualify.
What I would consider offensive:

- remarks about 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> grade relatives
- phrases involving genital organs
- TBD ... (feel free to pitch in)

Comment: Thanks, I agree. I've never worked with developers that don't swear. Diseases, genitals and remarks on family members are definitely not ok but the rest is fine by me too.

Comment: how about combining remarks about relatives and some organs? :)

Comment: @Marius I think I know a few of those in Romanian that you might be talking about and they are DEFINITELY not appropriate ;)